# Variable types for parameters in SML

Tags: list, types, sml

```
fun in_list (x : int, y : int list) =
if null y
then false
else if x=hd y then true
else in_list(x,tl y)
```

This is what my code currently looks like, it simply returns true if x appears in the the y list, false if not.  The issue is I want it to be able to input "a" and ["a", "b", "c"] as well, or even have x be a list, and y be a list of lists.  I am VERY new to ML (just started learning about it last week), and have searched for answers and cannot come up with anything.

Comment: Note: `if A then false else B` is just a complicated way of saying `not A andalso B`, and likewise, `if A then true else B` is just `A orelse B`. So your code could be written `not (null y) andalso (x = hd y orelse in_list(x, tl y))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the first line to

```
fun in_list (x : ''a, y : ''a list) =
```

then it will behave as you want. Here `''a` is an equality type variable that can stand for any type that supports the `=` operator.

You could also just leave out the types altogether and the most general correct type will be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Types can always be omitted in function declarations, with is only one exception: where overloading of operators could cause ambiguity. An example is

```
fun square x = x*x
```

because the type of x could be either int or real. (It will default to int, maybe not what you want.)

The point is that there is only one function hd. But the operator * can refer to two quite different functions.